# How to condense macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very long macro in my workbook which hides any blank cell in two tables in the first spreadsheet of the workbook. Every cell in these two tables are linked to two other tables (the table on the second spreadsheet and the table on the third spreadsheet respectively). The macro is working fine, I am just wondering if there is a way to condense the macro code I am writing. I have written the code for 3 of the sections so far but there are 32 sections total (10 rows in each section not including the header row) and 706 rows total (I have to write an If Statement for every single row).

```
Sub HideRowsInSOW2()
'First Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B28") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = True
    End If
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C29") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("29").Hidden = True
End If
'1A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C30") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("30").Hidden = True
End If
'1B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C31") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("31").Hidden = True
End If
'1C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C32") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("32").Hidden = True
End If
'1D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C33") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("33").Hidden = True
End If
'1E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C34") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("34").Hidden = True
End If
'1F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C34") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("34").Hidden = True
End If
'1G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C35") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("35").Hidden = True
End If
'1H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C36") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("36").Hidden = True
End If
'1J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C37") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("37").Hidden = True
End If
'1K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C38") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("38").Hidden = True
End If
'1L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C39") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("39").Hidden = True
End If
'1M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C40") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("40").Hidden = True
End If
'1N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C41") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("41").Hidden = True
End If
'1O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C42") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("42").Hidden = True
End If
'1P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C43") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("43").Hidden = True
End If
'1Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C44") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("44").Hidden = True
End If
'1R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C45") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("45").Hidden = True
End If
'1S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C46") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("46").Hidden = True
End If
'1T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C47") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("47").Hidden = True
End If
'1U
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C48") = 0 Then
      Worksheets("SOW").Rows("48").Hidden = True
End If
'Second Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B49") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("49:69").Hidden = True
 End If
'2A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C50") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("50").Hidden = True
 End If
'2B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C51") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("51").Hidden = True
 End If
'2C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C52") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("52").Hidden = True
 End If
'2D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C53") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("53").Hidden = True
 End If
'2E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C54") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("54").Hidden = True
 End If
'2F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C55") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("55").Hidden = True
 End If
'2G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C56") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("56").Hidden = True
 End If
'2H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C57") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("57").Hidden = True
 End If
'2I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C58") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("58").Hidden = True
 End If
'2J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C59") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("59").Hidden = True
 End If
'2K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C60") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("60").Hidden = True
 End If
'2L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C61") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("61").Hidden = True
 End If
'2M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C62") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("62").Hidden = True
 End If
'2N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C63") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("63").Hidden = True
 End If
'2O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C64") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("64").Hidden = True
 End If
'2P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C65") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("65").Hidden = True
 End If
'2Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C66") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("66").Hidden = True
 End If
'2R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C67") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("67").Hidden = True
 End If
'2S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C68") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("68").Hidden = True
 End If
'2T
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C69") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("69").Hidden = True
 End If
'3rd Section
If Sheets("SOW").Range("B70") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("70:90").Hidden = True
End If
'3A
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C71") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("71").Hidden = True
End If
'3B
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C72") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("72").Hidden = True
End If
'3C
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C73") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("73").Hidden = True
End If
'3D
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C74") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("74").Hidden = True
End If
'3E
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C75") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("75").Hidden = True
End If
'3F
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C76") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("76").Hidden = True
End If
'3G
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C77") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("77").Hidden = True
End If
'3H
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C78") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("78").Hidden = True
End If
'3I
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C79") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("79").Hidden = True
End If
'3J
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C80") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("80").Hidden = True
'3K
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C81") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("81").Hidden = True
End If
'3L
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C82") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("82").Hidden = True
End If
'3M
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C83") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("83").Hidden = True
End If
'3N
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C84") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("85").Hidden = True
End If
'3O
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C86") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("86").Hidden = True
End If
'3P
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C87") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("87").Hidden = True
End If
'3Q
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C88") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("88").Hidden = True
End If
'3R
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C89") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("89").Hidden = True
End If
'3S
If Sheets("SOW").Range("C90") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("90").Hidden = True
End If
```

My code is working, just need to know if there is a more efficient way to write it and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the rows:

```
Sub HideRowsInSOW2()
'First Section
    If Sheets("SOW").Range("B28") = 0 Then
          Worksheets("SOW").Rows("28:48").Hidden = True
    End If
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 29 To 90
        Worksheets("SOW").Rows(i).Hidden = Sheets("SOW").Cells(i, 3) = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @Scott Craner! Just a quick question before I test your code, shouldn't `For i = 29 To 90` be `For i = 29 to 48` since the first section goes up to row 48, not row 90?

Comment: Sure,  I just skimmed to the bottom and saw 90

Comment: I'm assuming I use this code 16 times for each section in the macro `Sub HideRowsInSOW2()`

Comment: No worries, Scott. Thanks again for your help! I'll test it out now and then up vote your response.

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried your macro but it didn't work. I got the error message: "Compile Error: Duplicate declaration in current scope."

Comment: You only declare i once.

Comment: There are multiple ranges besides B28 that I need to include though. B28 is the header row for the 20 rows that follow below. B28 and the other header rows are colored gray and have a drop down (in the original that B28 references) while 20 rows below are colored white. The other header row cells are B49, B70, B91, B112, B133, B154, B175, B196, B217, B238, B259, B280, B301, B371, B392, B413, B434, B455, B476, B497, B518, B539, B560, B581, B602, B623, B644, B665, and B686. So would I put all of those in the range in the first line and then 28:48, 50:69, 71:90...etc in the second line of code?

Comment: I tried doing what I asked about in my last comment. It worked partially. It hides all empty rows in both tables but it also hides the gray rows even though they have values in them.